# Reducer always returning initial state React-native

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, reducers

I want to use Reducers,redux,thunk. I have a sample code.
When I starting project, running with no error. I want to change email first letter appears and return the value Initial value.
I did use these codes with this package.json but when I update all libraries crash some functions. I share finale package.json file at the end of my post.
package.json file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-25.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.40.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-native": "^4.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Look at my gif please.
[Problem Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikF1w.gif)

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './src/reducers';
import Router from './src/Router';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Scene, Router, Stack} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Login from './components/Login';

const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router navigationBarStyle={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
      <Stack key="root">
          <Scene key="Login" component={Login} title="Giriş Yap" backTitle=" " hideNavBar={true} type="reset" initial/>
      </Stack>
    </Router>

  );
};

export default RouterComponent;
```

This is my Login.js
I want to change email or password in textinput return initial value

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser } from '../actions';
import { KucukButton } from '../ortak';

class Login extends Component {
  state ={ email: '', password: '', loading: false };

clickLogin() {
  const { email, password } = this.props;
  this.props.loginUser({ email, password });
}

loginSucces() {
  console.log('başarılı');
  this.setState({ loading: false });
}


loginFail() {
  console.log('Hatalı');
  this.setState({ loading: false });
  Alert.alert(
    'Mesaj',
    'Kullanıcı adı veya şifreniz hatalı!',
    [
      { text: 'Tamam', onPress: () => null }
    ]
  );
}
  render() {
    return (
       <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          flex: 1
        }}>
            <TextInput
              autoCapitalize="none"
              keyboardType="email-address"
              placeholder="örn hesap: test@test.com"
              placeholderTextColor="#000"
              value={this.props.email}
              onChangeText={email => this.props.emailChanged(email)}
            />
            <KucukButton yazisiz="hayir" onPress={this.clickLogin.bind(this)}> Giriş Yap </KucukButton>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({ kimlikdogrulamaResponse }) => {
  const {email, password }= kimlikdogrulamaResponse;
  return {
    email,
    password
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser })(Login);
```

and this is my actions.js

```
import { EMAIL_CHANGED, PASSWORD_CHANGED } from './types';

export const emailChanged = (email) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
      payload: email
    });
  };
};


export const passwordChanged = (password) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: PASSWORD_CHANGED,
      payload: password
    });
  };
};
```

types.js

```
export const EMAIL_CHANGED = 'email_changed';
export const PASSWORD_CHANGED = 'password_changed';
```

Reducers.js

```
import { EMAIL_CHANGED, PASSWORD_CHANGED } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: '00000000',
  password: ''
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAIL_CHANGED:
        return { ...state, email: action.payload };
    case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, password: action.payload };
  default:
      return state;

  }
};
```

finally my package.json file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^31.0.2",
    "firebase": "^5.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-native": "^4.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

EDIT::
you can look my snack for testing.
[Snack Expo Application](https://snack.expo.io/@wyrustaaruz/aGFzYW)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't dispatch any action.

In your `Login` component, you call your function defined in the `actions` file, but this returns another function which none calls.

You could try to map the props in your Login as:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    emailChanged: email => emailChanged(email)(dispatch)
});
```

Same as above for your password.

Even if this should work, your pattern here is a bit weird. In your case you can restructure your code in this way for a cleaner understanding:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    emailChanged: email => dispatch(emailChanged(email))
});
```

And your actions like:

```
export const emailChanged = email => ({
   type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
   payload: email
});
```

In both the above cases, introducing the mapDispatchToProps, then your `connect` should be something like:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution but it is not work.

Login.js:**
const mapStateToProps = ({ kimlikdogrulamaResponse }) => {
  const {email, password }= kimlikdogrulamaResponse;
  return {
    email,
    password
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  emailChanged: email => dispatch(emailChanged(email)),
  passwordChanged: password => dispatch(passwordChanged(password))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
**
actions.js**
export const emailChanged = email => ({
      type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
      payload: email
});**

Answer (score 0):

Now you dispatch every single keystroke, this is not best practice. Instead of doing this, you should write email and password values to the state.

```
<TextInput
    autoCapitalize="none"
    keyboardType="email-address"
    placeholder="örn hesap: test@test.com"
    placeholderTextColor="#000"
    defaultValue={this.props.email} //use defaultValue
    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})} //use state
/>
```

After that, you should dispatch this.state.email by your action creator in your login function.

```
clickLogin() {
    const {email, password} = this.props;
    this.props.emailChanged(this.state.email) //now you should dispatch
    this.props.loginUser({email, password});
}
```

Also you should use same way for password.

Comment: Thank you but it is not work. console log return undefined.

Comment: where is your console.log statement?